# Is the span of a subspace and its sympletic complement the entire space?

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

So for a finite-dimensional symplectic vector space $V$, the symplectic complement of a subspace $W$ is defined as:

$$
W^\omega=\{x \in V \mid \omega(x, y)=0 \text { for all } y \in W\}
$$

I was just wondering, does the span of $W$ and $W^\omega$ equal the entire space $V$? If not are there any counterexamples? We know the sum of the dimensions is, in fact, $V$ but I can't prove that the span is the entire space so I suspect it is not true.

Comment: $\dim W + \dim W^{\omega} = \dim V$ but it needs not to be space, for example Lagrangian subspace $W = W^\omega\subset V$

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the most elementary differences between symplectic linear algebra and the study of inner product spaces. An inner product $g$ on a vector space $V$ has the positive definite property: $g(v,v)\ge 0$ for $v\in V$, with $g(v,v)=0$ if and only if $v=0$. Completely in the opposite direction, for a symplectic form $\omega(v,v)=0$ for all $v\in V$.

Nondegeneracy of the alternating $2$-form $\omega$ implies $\dim W + \dim W^\omega = \dim V$ just as nondegeneracy of $g$ implies $\dim W +\dim W^\perp = \dim V$. However, the positive definiteness condition of $g$ guarantees $W \cap W^\perp = 0$. Therefore, $W \oplus W^\perp = V$.

In the symplectic case, $W\cap W^\omega = 0$ is not necessarily the case. As Yi Li points out - take any Lagrangian subspace of $V$. More generally, take an isotropic subspace : one so that $W\subset W^\omega$. A dimension count shows $W+W^\omega \ne V$.